# Add Field to SPUserProfile

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, user-profile

I need to add Field to `User Profile`. Is there a way using OTB to add Field. For example: `Add Field 'code' to the UserProfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my environment (SharePoint 2013 on-prem) you can add a field via the central administration.

1. Go to the User Profile Administation

[image]

2. Click on Manage User Properties

[image]

3. And then click on New Property

[image]

Then you can specify the new property and some other settings for that specific property.

Hope this helps.